# I have open cv library in my computer but when I am trying to import it is showing module not found error

Tags: python, opencv, pip

i have installed the open cv library through pip command and it shows that requirement already satisfied but when i am trying to import it shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ayush Thakur\Desktop\python projects\image matcher.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

while it also shows:

```
PS C:\Users\Ayush Thakur> pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\ayush thakur\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (4.8.1.78)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\ayush thakur\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.26.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

there's not a lot of information being provided. but seeing how you're using windows and pip is working. i'm assuming you are having version issues, and since you are having issues with starting python, i am assuming you are new to python. and there's 1 main reason i see this issue, and it's because of bad tutorials and/or pycharm.

it's a very common mistake among newbies to have multiple versions of python. most times this happens when an IDE that tried to make you do "optimal" things or solve issues as easily as possible. if this is the case, instead of running this from pycharm, the fastest solution would be to run the 3 following commands:

```
cd c:\Users\Ayush Thakur\Desktop\python projects
python -m pip install opencv-python
python "image matcher.py"
```

basically, you first run `cd` to go into the directory where `image matcher.py` is. after doing that, you run `python -m pip install opencv-python` to make sure you don't have 2 versions of pip, and that you are spesifically using python's pip. and after all of these, running "image matcher.py" should have no reason not to find cv2.

this is only a temporery solution though. if this solves the issue, tell me and i'l help you make it permanent